# Prolog embedding in java help

Tags: java, prolog

| have a filter written in prolog which i would like to embed in my web service. I am using JAVA at my back end, I would like the filter to be added here. I am using tomcat as my applicaton server. Can anyone suggest a good way. I am aware of JPL, the sad part is I am not able to get it working.

Comment: Your question should then be related to the JPL issue, make sure you include the error your seeing

Answer (score 3):

There's always [tuProlog](http://www.alice.unibo.it/xwiki/bin/view/Tuprolog/) if you want to embed your Prolog engine into Java itself.  Other alternatives would include the similar-in-concept [JLog](http://jlogic.sourceforge.net/) or the more compilerish [Prolog Cafe](http://kaminari.scitec.kobe-u.ac.jp/prologcafe/).

Another alternative, perhaps a bit more distant (it will certainly involve a bit of porting effort on your part) is to use the [Mercury](http://www.mercury.csse.unimelb.edu.au/) language – it has a very Prolog-ish syntax, but is not actually Prolog – which features, among other things, a Java back-end and commensurate Java FFI.

Answer (score 0):

It's not immediately obvious what you're trying to do so I'm going to make the assumption that you're really just trying to puzzle out how to launch your Prolog code and get the results back.

If that's the case, Java provides the [Process](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) classes:

> The ProcessBuilder.start() and
>   Runtime.exec methods create a native
>   process and return an instance of a
>   subclass of Process that can be used
>   to control the process and obtain
>   information about it. The class
>   Process provides methods for
>   performing input from the process,
>   performing output to the process,
>   waiting for the process to complete,
>   checking the exit status of the
>   process, and destroying (killing) the
>   process.

Perhaps more immediately useful is the [ProcessBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html): this allows you to create a full working environment (including the environment variables) that closely simulates the command line that you're probably testing with now.  Quoting from the Javadoc:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("myCommand", "myArg1", "myArg2");
Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
env.put("VAR1", "myValue");
env.remove("OTHERVAR");
env.put("VAR2", env.get("VAR1") + "suffix");
pb.directory(new File("myDir"));
Process p = pb.start();
```

Remember, if you want to pass information to the Process that you created, you need to use the [Process.getOutputStream()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getOutputStream%28%29) (that would be your output to the Prolog's input).  Likewise, if you want to get the Prolog's output and errors, you need to use `Process.getInputStream()` and `Process.getErrorStream()`.

I've confused those input and output streams in the past and still wish that I could have those hours of my life back....